# T-SQL Script to Change SQL Server Logins From SQL Server Auth to Windows Auth

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone have some insight into switching the authentication mode of Logins in SQL Server for sql server authentication to windows authentication by script?

We have too many to simply run through each in SSMS.

The T-SQL solution I've arrived at is to recreate the logins new (and then recreating the users, and the roles ...) but with WINDOWS auth, and remove the old ones (and users...) but this is fraught with risks.

Comment: I don't think you can change login type. You mention doing so through SSMS but when I open login properties in SSMS, the radio buttons for the login type are disabled. I think your plan (drop and recreate) is the only one that will work.

Comment: You're correct - can't be done via SSMS. Drop and recreate it is then. Thanks.

Comment: You can still make it via a script, though. I think dynamic SQL is a way to go here - iterate through all logins (except - you know - yourself, sa etc), drop them and create as windows auth. I think it's not too much of a hassle.

Comment: For sure, yes. Good suggestion. The users to switch will be derived from an application user table and this can feed into dynamlc SQL.. Just easier in mind to change the login account auth method than determining and recreating all the database users the login's map to with all the different roles in those databases some people have and others don't, in addition to creating a new login.

Comment: edit - changed comment to answer

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of final solutions and closure - I'll bring in the windows accounts through AD groups, with the groups mapped to databases+roles, and do tons of clean-up with the existing SQL server login and user accounts